# Is there a way to delete RAW files from Aperture?

Tags: raw, apple-aperture, workflow, file-management

I currently shoot everything in RAW+JPEG and import into Aperture as pairs.  I have a large number of photos that I have not (and will not) make adjustments to and it would be nice to remove the RAW files to free up some disk space.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aperture treats the RAW file and the JPEG as a single composite master and won't let you do anything with them individually except create a new master from the JPEG. That new master can be deleted, but it doesn't buy you anything since the original RAW is still there with the JPEG file.

> **The RAW and JPEG images are treated as a single master.** In a RAW+JPEG
>   workflow, the two images are treated
>   as a single master. If you have
>   imported the images as referenced,
>   avoid deleting either the RAW or JPEG
>   from the Finder - Aperture will lose
>   connection with the remaining master
>   as well.([Source](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA24505?viewlocale=en_US))

There are ways to delete the RAW files using finder, or terminal scripts, but none that use Aperture such as what your original question asked.

Comment: A complex way to delete them using finder: http://archive.bagelturf.com/aparticles/library/deljpeg/index.php
An even more complex way to delete RAW files using terminal:
http://blogs.oreilly.com/aperture/2007/09/getting-rid-of-unwanted-manage-1.html